# Can two precipitates form in a precipitation reaction that starts with only two compounds in water?

Tags: aqueous-solution, solubility

Can two precipitates form in a precipitation reaction that starts with only two compounds in water?

Comment: Could you add a little bit of discussion why you think it should or should not be possible? Judging by the phrasing of your question I think you know reactions that form 1 precipitate in such a situation? How much do you know about the thermodynamics of these kind of reactions?

Comment: I think his question is: can two salts react to precipitate two new salts?

Comment: Actually, I'm confused by the title. Does the OP mean "only two molecules"? This means **exactly two molecules**. Or does the OP mean "only two compounds", with the amount of each compound open to interpretation?

Comment: I don't see why this should be closed - it seems a perfectly reasonable question to me

Comment: I suggested a long clarification because I understood it and I wasn't sure why other people didn't so I thought I should be thorough, but I just realized that it had already been edited and, based on Ben Norris's comment, was probably much more confusing originally. I suspect Gaurang Tandon's or whoever else's edits were enough and many people already understood the question.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The number of examples is considerably great.
Consider the following:

$$\ce{Ba(OH)2(aq) + MgSO4(aq)  -> BaSO4(s) + Mg(OH)2(s)} $$

Above reactants are reasonably soluble in water.
From Wikipedia, $\ce{Ba(OH)2} $ has a solubility of 1.67 g / 100 mL at 20 °C and $\ce{MgSO4} $ a solubility of 25.5 g / 100 mL at 20 °C

Answer (score 0):

Yes is the answer to your question provided that reactant two molecules are salts.Two salts can react with eact other and form two new stable salts depending on their $\mathrm{K}_{sp}$ values.